# Get first two characters of a rendered data from database

Tags: vue.js

How do I get the first two characters of a rendered data from Database?

```vue
<div v-for="(schedule,index) in DailySchedule" v-bind:key="index">
  <span class="days-div"> 
    <span class="day" v-for="(days,index) in schedule" v-bind:key="index.id">
      <span v-for="(day,index) in days" v-bind:key="index.id" >
        {{day.day}} 
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>   
<div>
```

Data Declaration : 
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "days": [
        {
          "id": 12,
          "day": "monday",
          "start_time": "10:00:00",
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "day": "tuesday",
        }
]

Output data is:

```
monday wednesday thursday
```

But I want it rendered as `M W Th`.

Comment: can't it be "Su Mo ... Fr Sa "?

Comment: yes its possible can u help me with this

Comment: im still newbie at vuejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have between the curly braces is javascript. So you should be able to use this :

```
{{day.day.substring(0, 2)}}
```

This will take character 0 (included) to character 2 (excluded) of your string. More on the substring function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

[Here is a JSFiddle that works, using your code](https://jsfiddle.net/v6ty70sf/)

**Update :**
You posted the following data :

```
"data":[
    {
       "id":2,
       "days":[
           {
              "id":12,
              "day":"monday",
              "start_time":"10:00:00",
           },
           {
              "id":13,
              "day":"tuesday",
           }
       ]
```

I suppose it is incomplete since there are trailing commas. But extrapolating from this, if you want to loop through the days, your `<template>` part should look like this :

```
  <span v-for="(day,index) in days" v-bind:key="day.id" >
      {{day.day}} 
  </span>
```

This is because of the format of your data, you have three `v-for` in your template, this means your `DailySchedule` object should exist and be at least three levels deep. watch out for the `v-bind:key` too : you declared `index.id` but `index` is not an object, it is an integer, you can either declare `index` or `day.id` (because there is an `id` field in your `day` object)

---

Also if this is a copy paste from the declaration of your data object in vue.js, there is another problem : `data` should be a `function` like this (I updated the fiddle to give you an exemple) :

```
data: function () {
    return {
        days: [
           {
              "id":12,
              "day":"monday",
              "start_time":"10:00:00",
           },
           {
              "id":13,
              "day":"tuesday",
           }
        ]
        //declare your other variables here
    }
},
```

Comment: tried that one and it says "cannot read property of substring"

Comment: could you post your vue.js data declaration too please ?

Comment: @NyaaNyaaA That sounds like a whole different issue.

Comment: Please edit your oiriginal post to post code, this is way more readable. Also you use an item named `DailySchedule` in your code but it does not appear in what you just posted ? Finally, I added a link in my answer to a fiddle that works with your code + the substring method to display `Mo`, `Tu`, `We`. if this can help.

Comment: thanks! yeah this thing works and i think i have a different issue here

Comment: if you post the object you use (`DailySchedule`) we might be able to help you with the real problem too :)

Comment: If you look at the JSFiddle, you will see that I declare a `DailySchedule` . The data you posted does not have such an object. I updated my answer, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `vue filters` like this:

```
export default {
    data: () => {
      return { 
      }
    },
    created(){
    },
    filters: {
        truncate: function (text, length, suffix) {
            return text.substring(0, length) + suffix;
        },
    }
}
```

or

```
Vue.filter('truncate', function (text, length, suffix) {
    return text.substring(0, length) + suffix;
});
```

then use it like this:

```
<span v-for="(day,index) in days" v-bind:key="index.id" >
    {{day.day | truncate(2, '')}} //result would be Mo
    {{day.day | truncate(3, '...')}} //result would be Mon...
</span>
```

If you want to know more vue filters, I suggest you read this: [How to Create Filters in Vue.js with Examples](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-filters-in-vuejs-with-examples)